# Aligning DevExpress DockPanel Header Text

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have multiple dynamic DevExpress DockPanels loaded on an asp.net(aspx) page. I would like to change the DockPanel Header text to be center aligned. I've searched through the DevExpress documentation but cannot find and samples showing how to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [ASPxDocking](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Docking/index.xml)

> Customizable header and footer content. Both elements allow you to
>   display a glyph and text (or a hyperlink). Note that you can also use
>   templates for more flexible header and footer content customization.

Reference : [Panel Header](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9794)

I suggest you to set the [ASPxPopupControlBase.HeaderTemplate Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlASPxPopupControlBase_HeaderTemplatetopic) or create custom header template as suggested in the example.

code snippet:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div style="text-align:right;">
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="close" onclick="
        if(document.getElementById('checkBox').checked)
            popupControl.Hide();
    "/>            
    </div>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Hope this help..